# Cakephp sessions www and http url formats

Tags: cakephp

I am having problems with CakePHP2.0 login sessions and cookies.

When i login from the website with "http://myweb.com" at the start, the user is only loged it if he keeps on the same URL. 
If he changes to "http://www.myweb.com", then it seems that the user is not loged in anymore and the system requieres from username and password again when he tries to add a post or something similar.

I am using CakePHP function, the one that createds by default with the "cake bake".
Why is this happening?

Does it have any solution?
THanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you add this to your bootstrap.php it should make the sign-in work with the www or not

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.myweb.com');
```

That being said - it is always a good idea to pick a canonical url with or without the www and redirect your users to that.

You decide whether or not you want your domain to include a www and re-direct your users to that one instead of letting them decide.

Comment: It doesn't work for me using that code. I am using CakePHP 2.0.

Anyway, i think i will opt for your suggestion, i also read about it here: http://ask.cakephp.org/questions/view/problem_with_sessions_with_http_and_www

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

@see my answer to your double post at http://ask.cakephp.org/questions/view/problem_with_sessions_with_http_and_www